# Deflection problem confusing units?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image]

Everytime I try this question I keep getting 93.75 mm. I was just wondering where I'm going wrong. Here's my work:

$$
BC=\dfrac{FL}{AE}=\dfrac{1500000\text{ N}\cdot 1250\text{ mm}}{100000\text{ mm}^2*200\text{ MPa}}=93.75\text{ mm}
$$
For deflection to be in $\text{mm}$, all units have to be in $\text{N}$ and $\text{mm}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The book probably meant $E = 200\text{ GPa}$, which is frequently adopted for steel.

To confirm, I made a simple little model:

[image]

You're probably aware of this, but just to make it explicit: your math only worked because $200\text{ MPa} = 200\text{ N/mm}^2$.

Comment: yeah ok i thought it was something like that and yes i know that MPa is N/mm^2 so everything cancels out to leaves mm. Thanks again